# OG action with multiple objects: How to setup the story attachment captions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action

I have a single Open Graph action which can be connected to multiple objects with different attributes. And because of the completely different nature of those objects, the action connects to one of them at a time.

Now I want to setup the story attachment section for my action and I've chosen the *Item* layout which allows 4 lines of captions. I can setup this section and use it successfully for one of the objects:

```
Caption 1: {object1.field1}
Caption 2: {object1.field2}
Caption 3: {object1.field3}
Caption 4: {object1.field4}
```

**But here is the question:** How do I setup the captions to work with the second and third objects as well?! I've tried to put the second object at the same line with the first one, like (although they are not used together):

```
Caption 1: {object1.field1} {object2.field1}
```

The end result is that the above line is never displayed neither for *object1* nor for *object2* because one of them is always absent! If you list more than one field in a caption line and one of the fields have no value, Facebook will completely omit the whole line.

On the other hand, Facebook does not allow me to add another *Item layout* for my other objects to setup them separately! Any idea?

Thank you,